# '[Error] Execution (8: 3): ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at line 5' in the following plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

thanks for all,i had modified from varchar2(10) to varchar2(20) and removing the column keyword in execute immediate statement then program is executing

```
declare
coldate varchar2(20);
colname varchar2(20);
begin
    coldate :='varchar2(10)';
    colname :='smaple';
    execute immediate 'alter table smap1 add column '||colname ||' '||coldate ;
end;
```

if i want to take the values dynamically i had used the following code

```
declare
coldate varchar2(20):=&coldate;
colname varchar2(20):=&colname;
begin
   execute immediate 'alter table smap1 add '||colname ||' '||coldate ;
end;
```

then i am getting errors

```
 [Error] Execution (11: 23): ORA-06550: line 2, column 23:
 PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
 ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
 PL/SQL: Item ignored
 ORA-06550: line 3, column 23:
 PLS-00201: identifier 'SMAPLE' must be declared
 ORA-06550: line 3, column 9:
 PL/SQL: Item ignored
 ORA-06550: line 6, column 45:
 PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
 ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: `'varchar2(10)'` is 12 characters, you're reserving space for only 10.

Comment: thanks for all,i had modified from `varchar2(10)` to `varchar2(20)` but i am getting another error in the program that is **ORA-00904: : invalid identifier ORA-06512: at line 7**

Comment: See my answer below instead, added the details there.

Comment: thanks, i had modified the code but the still the query executed with errors

Comment: You may want to add all details when you're _creating_ the question, not add complexity as you go. Deleting my answer since it was an answer to your original question, not the updated one.

Comment: my intention is to create the table dynamically with number of columns and dynamically assigning column name and their data types by using a plsql block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    declare
    coldate varchar2(20);
    colname varchar2(20);
    begin
        coldate :='varchar2(10)';
        colname :='smaple';
        execute immediate 'alter table smap1 add column '||colname ||' '||coldate ;
    end;

    This query wont work as syntactically its not correct.
    Please try this as it will help you definitely

    declare
    coldate varchar2(20):='varchar2(20)';
    colname varchar2(20):='Newadd';
    begin
       execute immediate 'alter table <tablename> add '||colname ||' '||coldate ;
    end;
-- And to use dynamically input values Please try this

SET DEFINE ON;
declare
coldate varchar2(20):='&DATATYPE';
colname varchar2(20):='&COL_NAME';
begin
   execute immediate 'alter table emp add '||colname ||' '||coldate ;
end;
```

Comment: thank you this program is working.I want to read the column name and datatype at run time execution of the program

Comment: Hi Use thisSET DEFINE ON;
declare
coldate varchar2(20):='&DATATYPE';
colname varchar2(20):='&COL_NAME';
begin
   execute immediate 'alter table emp add '||colname ||' '||coldate ;
end;

Answer (score 0):

The below will solve it:

```
coldate varchar2(12);
colname varchar2(20);
begin
    coldate :='varchar2(10)';
```